# Generate an accumulated array of strings from a string array

Tags: r, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have this:

```
str <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
```

And I want to generate the following array of strings:

```
"c ~ var1"
"c ~ var1 + var2"
"c ~ var1 + var2 + var3"
```

I know I can hardcode this, since there are only 3 strings, but I want a method for a vector of any size. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
out <- vector()
out[1] <- paste("c ~",str[1])
for (i in 2:length(str)) out[i] <- paste(out[i-1], "+", str[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")

for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  vars <- paste(x[1:i], collapse = " + ")
  print(paste("c ~", vars))
}

# [1] "c ~ var1"
# [1] "c ~ var1 + var2"
# [1] "c ~ var1 + var2 + var3"
```

*N.B. Try to avoid assigning variables to names of existing functions (e.g. `str` -- look at `?str`)*

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
> lapply(sapply(1:length(str), seq), function(x){ 
      paste0("c ~ ",paste(str[x],collapse=" + ")) })
[[1]]
[1] "c ~ var1"

[[2]]
[1] "c ~ var1 + var2"

[[3]]
[1] "c ~ var1 + var2 + var3"
```

You can change `lapply` to `sapply` to get character vector.

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative using "formula" objects:

```
lapply(Reduce(function(x, y) setNames(data.frame(x, y), 
                                      c(names(x), y)), 
              str, init = c(c = "c"), acc = TRUE)[-1L], 
       formula)
#[[1]]
#c ~ var1
#<environment: 0x0321adcc>
#
#[[2]]
#c ~ var1 + var2
#<environment: 0x0321adcc>
#
#[[3]]
#c ~ var1 + var2 + var3
#<environment: 0x0321adcc>
```

If a "character" object is really needed, then we could `lapply(., deparse)` on the above or if the final goal is a formula, instead of `lapply` we could loop with `for` to preserve the original "environment".